# ¿Como crear un loadpage cuando se este generando un excel ? ASP MVC

Tags: html, c#, vb.net, asp.net-mvc

Me podrían ayudar en como crear un loadpag en ASP MVC, ya que me encuentro realizando una pagina en la cual se crearan reportes. Al momento de que se este recopilando la información (Obteniendo datos de un Stored Procedure) y posteriormente pasar la información a un reporte en Excel quiero que me muestre un loadpage que diga recabando información etc... con un gif para mostrarle al usuario.
La parte de obtener la info y crear el excel ya la tengo solo me falta agregarle el loadpage para mostrárselo al usuario.
Soy nuevo en ASP MVC.
Espero y me puedan ayudar.
Saludos.

Comment: Hola Andres, por favor lee [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  y modifica tu pregunta para poder ayudarte. Saludos.

Comment: que seria lo de "recopilando la información"? es una especie de wizard o sea navegas entre varias paginas o es solo una que completa y realiza el submit

Comment: @LeandroTuttini si lo que pasa es que se conecta a la base de datos busca la informacion de un stored procedure y con el resultado se crea un Excel  ,pero mientras ocurre eso quiero poner un loadpage para que el usuario no se desespere y le pique o casas asi.

Comment: entiendo, el tema es vas a tener que lanzar el proceso de generacion y descarga usando ajax, porque si usas un submit la pagina se actualiza y no vas a poder bloquearla

Comment: @LeandroTuttini asi es ,bueno la vdd no se usar ajax y js lo he usado poco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias ayudarte con `jquery` para mostrar el mensaje que bloquea la pantalla cuando se realiza el submit

[Locking the Screen During a Postback](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506152543/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/121708-1.aspx)

La idea es que en el click del boton que defines como `type=sumbit` te adjuntes con un evento jquery para poder mostrar el bloqueo del boton o de la pagina.

La clave esta aqui

```
<input type="submit" value="Click Me!" onclick="skm_LockScreen('We are processing your request...');" />
```

Es en el `click` del `submit` donde realizas el bloqueo de la pagina

Sino la otra aleternativa seria usar el `@Ajax.BeginForm()` con este puede definir `LoadingElementId`  para desplegar el indicador de progreso

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AjaxMethod", "Home",
                new AjaxOptions
                {
                    OnSuccess = "OnSuccess",
                    OnFailure = "OnFailure",
                    LoadingElementId = "progress"
                }))
{
```